# Post request in angular/tornado website

Tags: angularjs, tornado

I have problem with making post request. Below codes fails when user tries to submit the form, tornado handler.get_argument('login') and handler.get_argument('password') both return None, while I clearly send those data. What is even more interesting, when I change method from post to get, everything works fine. How to make it work with post request too?

```
//angular js
angular.module('playItApp', ['playItControllers', 'playItServices']);

angular.module('playItServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('users', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/user');
    }]);

angular.module('playItControllers', [])
    .controller('authentication', ['users', function(users){
        this.register = function(){
            users.save({'login': this.login, 'password': this.password});
        };
    }]);

# tornado handler
class User(JsonHandler):
    def post(self):
        login = self.get_argument('login')
        password = self.get_argument('password')
        user = self.db.create_user(login, password)
        self.set_secure_cookie('user', str(user['id']))
        self.write(user)

<div ng-controller="authentication as authentication">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" ng-model="authentication.login">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="authentication.password">
        <button ng-click="authentication.register()">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is (probably) sending the POST data as JSON, but `get_argument` is for form-encoded data. You'll have to either use `json.loads(self.request.body)` instead of `get_argument` if you want to stick with JSON, or you should be able to get Angular to send form-encoded data instead. If you care about compatibility with non-javascript clients, you may want to switch to form-encoded data, but if you're comfortable requiring javascript then using JSON is probably the better option.